# Exit Linux in DRAM to run bare-metal code in SRAM

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

**Question without the details:**

Is it possible to copy a bare-metal executable from Linux, running from DDR, into the processor internal SRAM and run it? This application would suspend the DDR and disable a power supply rail to fix a hardware problem.

**Details:**

I'm working on a custom embedded product using an ARM processor and running embedded Linux. The processor is an Atmel ATSAMA5D36. We're using the following secondary bootloader and kernel:

- https://github.com/linux4sam/at91bootstrap
- https://github.com/linux4sam/linux-at91

The current boot process is approximately this:

- The Atmel has a ROM bootloader that finds our bootloader on NOR flash and copies it to the SAMA5's internal SRAM
- The second level bootloader initializes hardware and copies/decompresses our kernel from NOR flash in LPDDR
- We jump into the kernel and run linux out of the LPDDR

The device operates in two modes: connected to main power or backed up by a battery. When connected to main power a command can be issued to suspend linux which puts our LPDDR memory into self-refresh mode. Once the LPDDR is in self-refresh main power can be removed and the LPDDR will be sustained until the next power-on cycle. There is a small secondary ARM Cortex-M0 microcontroller on the board that runs all the time and does IO handling and a few other time-related tasks.

**The Problem:**

When main power is removed from the board the battery switches over to power the LPDDR, secondary ARM microcontroller, and the main SAMA5 power goes down. When power is removed from the SAMA5, and the power supply caps discharge, the processor briefly (100uS) browns out and forces IO into a reset state before turning off for good. Unfortunately this "blip" in the power pulls the LPDDR CKE line high long enough to make the LPDDR to exit self-refresh mode. This causes memory corruption on the LPDDR.

Scope plot showing the main supply voltage and the DDR_CKE signal:

[image: Scope Plot]

To fix this problem we need to suspend the LPDDR and then tell the PMIC to disable the DDR_IO supply on the processor (the IO supply and main supply for the DDR are separate regulators). This would prevent the power blip that pops the LPDDR out of self-refresh. Unfortunately this is a chicken-or-the-egg problem. If we suspend the LPDDR we can't run any code to communicate to the PMIC and disable the specific supply. If we disable the supply we can no longer communicate to the LPDDR to put it into self-refresh.

**The Current Workaround:**

When the command is issued to suspend the main processor it forwards this to the secondary microcontroller and then suspends the LPDDR to self-refresh. The secondary microcontroller then resets the main processor and waits for the secondary bootloader to come up. When the bootloader starts, it checks with the microcontroller to see if a suspend was issued. If it was, it puts the LPDDR into self-refresh, tells the PMIC (via I2C) to disable the DDR_IO power supply, and sits in a while(1) waiting for power to be removed.

The issue with this is the boot time -- it takes 120ms from reset to DDR init and suspend. The LPDDR has a 16-64ms refresh cycle so we're missing at least one refresh cycle of the DDR. In testing so far we haven't seen memory corruption because of this delay but this is obviously a less-than-ideal solution (but  better than a hardware revision).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about system/hardware configuration, not ptogramming. Fix the hardware failure, if necessary hire someone with more expertise than your current "design engineer".

Comment: Although there are a lot of hardware details in the question, it is fundamentally a software question -- how do I (or can I) write code to perform the specified action.  It may be too broad, but I don't think it's off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just circling back to answer this question. It is, in fact, possible to load code from DRAM into SRAM and execute it. Upon further investigation we found that many embedded platforms use this method to handle power management functions, especially suspend/resume -- exactly like the problem I was trying to solve here.

Here's how linux handles entering suspend on the at91 platform: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mach-at91/pm.c#L416

We needed a custom implementation of this and ended up creating a kernel module that used the same method. We then inserted the kernel module from user-land and it gave us a way to run code from SRAM to execute our power management functions.

### Example Kernel Module Code:

```
#include <linux/io.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

#define VIRT_BASE 0xFEF78000 //for AT91

static void (*sram_fn)(void) = NULL;

unsigned char buf[] = {
    //your complied ARM byte code
};

static void __init init_sram_fn (void)
{
    sram_fn = (void *) (VIRT_BASE – sizeof(buf));
    memcpy(sram_fn, &buf, sizeof(buf));
    sram_fn();
}

static void __exit cleanup_sram_fn (void){}

module_init(init_sram_fn);
module_exit(cleanup_sram_fn);
```

### Invocation from user-land

```
system("insmod custom_pm_module.ko");
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to copy a bare-metal executable from Linux, running from DDR, into the processor internal SRAM and run it?

It is from very hard to impossible, depending on your platform. Linux kernel itself runs from DRAM, so when DRAM is off, you will have no live linux kernel and no any OS services (no syscalls, no scheduler, no irqs/irq handlers; no irq vector if it was in dram?).

Your chip has only 128 KB of SRAM: http://www.atmel.com/devices/ATsama5d36.aspx?tab=parameters - it is just to small to contain full Linux kernel.

So, you may try to create some executable, change its priority to RT (realtime) to be able to ignore the scheduler/irqs... You should put this executable fully to SRAM (only if the SRAM can be used as directly addressed memory)... You also should check that when it is needed, it will be loaded (or should you make the executable to be running all time on core? Is it multicore chip?)

It can be bit easier to write this not as executable, but as part of kernel... Still the task looks like impossible...

What is the time while DRAM and CPU are running before DRAM will be turned off?

DRAM may hold data for several refresh cycles; it will hold most data for seconds (longer with cooling - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_boot_attack; shorter when hot). You may probably want to add some data checksumming... (your chip has no ECC for DRAM?)